# Trigger click does not auto play YouTube video in a modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have below code and want to open the modal on page load. As a regular onload function did not work, I tried it with the triggering of the click. But that also does not auto play the video, while when I manually click the `span` it does.

Any idea why?

```
<div id="videoModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video" class="video" src="" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kLKOO_-MYKg?modestbranding=0&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1"></iframe>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            var videoSrc = $("#video").data('video');
            $("#videoModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
              $("#videoModal iframe").attr('src', '');
            });
            $("#videoModal").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
              $("#video").attr("src", videoSrc+"&autoplay=1");
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
              $("#launch").click(); // this does not auto play the video
            }, 200);
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- manually clicking this will launch the modal and auto play the video --> 
<span id="launch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">click</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: Just add `allow="autoplay"` to the iframe did the trick